# c# .net 4.0 throttling pattern for asyncronous download

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.0

Please pay attantion that it must be .NET 4.0 code only! Using async/await keywords and Task class are allowed. But in .NET 4.0 there are no methods like WhenAny().

I have a task to programm function that will:

```
///Return the content of required uris.
/// Method has to use the asynchronous way. 
/// maxConcurrentStreams parameter should control the maximum of 
/// concurrent streams that are running at the same time (throttling).

/// <param name="uris">Sequence of required uri</param>
/// <param name="maxConcurrentStreams">Max count of concurrent request streams</param>
/// <returns>The sequence of downloaded url content</returns>
public static IEnumerable<string> GetUrlContentAsync(this IEnumerable<Uri> uris, int maxConcurrentStreams)
{
.... ???
}
```

So. The question is to download string data(just html) by the uri with maximum of concurrent strem that are running at the same time(throttling).

Comment: What does `.NET 4.0 only` mean? .NET 4.0 is no longer supported, and C# 6.0 came out with 4.5. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. TLS 1.2 is supported only with 4.5.2 and later, so anything TCP related should target 4.5.2 at least

Comment: What kind of throttling do you want? Specify this in the question text, not the comments.

Comment: what are you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `await` in .NET 4.0, then you also have `TaskEx.WhenAny`.

Your options are:

1. [Build an AsyncSemaphore](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-5-asyncsemaphore/)
2. Use [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) (from [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/6/F967673D-58D6-4E3F-8CA9-11769A0A63B1/TPLDataflow.msi))
3. Use [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx) (from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/rx-main/2.2.5))

With any of these approaches, the return type of `IEnumerable<T>` is probably incorrect, unless you *want* to download everything before the first result is available.